# SQL: How to find entry that appears more than twice with specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find table entry that appears more than once with certain value

```
    Name | ID 
==================
    Peter   1
    James   2
    Peter   2
    James   2
```

I want to select entries where ID is both 1 and 2, in this example only Peter appears twice with value 1 and 2 while James appear twice but ID of James is not 1 and 2

Is there operator for this kind of query?

Comment: There is: `COUNT()`. Have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far?

Comment: I did try count but I want Peter to have 1 and 2 because when I used count it returned Peter and James, instead of returning just Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select name
from t
where id in (1, 2)
group by name
having count(distinct id) = 2;
```

Comment: it works great, I did not know there is a way to use count in this way. thank you